# How to replace a word only if it is followed and preceded by a space?

Tags: python, string

I want to replace the word `bacteria` in this sentence

`'List all the bacteria whose <http://bacteria> is bacillus ?'`

When I use `text.replace('bacteria','<e0>')`, it replaces also the `bacteria in <http://bacteria>` which I don't want and the string becomes `'List all the <e0> whose <http://<e0>> is bacillus ?'`

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use regex for this pretty easily as well

```
import re
new_string = re.sub("(?<=[ ^])bacteria(?=[ $])","",target_string)
```

this replaces all occurances that are preceded by the start of the string or a space, and followed by the end of the string or a space ... if you wanted to also replace say `"hello bacteria."` you could simply include `\.` in your list of lookbehind/lookahead characters

`re.sub("(?<=[\. ^])bacteria(?=[\. $])","",target_string)`

regex can get quite complicated rather fast however, so you really really really need to have your problem well defined

Comment: How to use any word other than bacteria in the above regex?

Comment: This regex doesn't work if bacteria comes at first position, what to do?

Comment: it should ... ^ is the start of string

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
text = 'List all the bacteria whose http://bacteria is bacillus ?'
new_text = ' '.join(word if word != 'bacteria' else '<e0>'
                    for word in text.split(' '))
```

Here is the `new_text` value:

```
'List all the <e0> whose http://bacteria is bacillus ?'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say you have two very easy options here, or if you have more variable needs, use regex:

1. Python's `replace` built-in allows you to specify the number of replacements that should be made. ex: `text.replace('bacteria', '<e0>', 1)` if you know the one you want to replace will come first.
2. You can use `text.replace(' bacteria ', ' <e0> ')` or something similar if you only want to replace instances surrounded by spaces.

Comment: Best answer if your problem is that simple.